# How yacc knows for look ahead

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lalr

How could yacc knows to shift `*` but not to reduce `T to E` in line 10

```
STACK       INPUT BUFFER    ACTION
$           num1+num2*num3$ shift
$num1       +num2*num3$     reduc
$F          +num2*num3$     reduc
$T          +num2*num3$     reduc
$E          +num2*num3$     shift
$E+     num2*num3$          shift
$E+num2 *num3$              reduc
$E+F        *num3$              reduc
$E+T        *num3$              shift      /////****//
E+T*        num3$              shift       /////****//
E+T*num3    $                  reduc
E+T*F       $                  reduc
E+T         $                  reduc
E           $                  accept
```

Does it automatically design table?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the trace you've provided, I'm guessing that the grammar looks like this:

- E → T | E + T
- T → F | T * F
- F → num

Without specifying otherwise, `yacc` uses the LALR(1) parsing algorithm, which uses a token of lookahead to help break ties when determining whether to perform a shift or reduce action. At the point you indicated, the parser had `T` on its stack with a lookahead of `*`. Notice that, in the grammar, there is no way for a `*` symbol to legally follow an `T` nonterminal in any derivation (formally, `*` ∉ FOLLOW(`T`)). That means that the parser knows not to reduce here, since LALR(1) will never reduce on a lookahead that isn't in the FOLLOW set for the given nonterminal.

To see how this works rigorously, you could construct the LALR(1) parsing automaton for this grammar and look at the lookaheads associated with each item. In that state, there will be two items, a completed item of the form

> T → F

and the following shift item:

> T → T .* F

The reduce item will not have `*` in its lookahead set (I believe it will just have `$`), so the LALR(1) state for the parser will look like this:

> T → F. [$]
>
> T → T .* F [$]

As a result, when the parser sees a `*`, it knows not to do the reduction and instead to shift, since the lookahead set for the reduce item doesn't contain a `*`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the FOLLOW set is used for SLR(1) parser construction -- LALR(1) and LR(1) track lookaheads on a per-state basis, which for a few corner cases works better.  But for this example, SLR(1), LALR(1), and LR(1) will all be exactly the same.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Definitely. LALR(1) parsers use LA sets, which are subsets of FOLLOW sets. As a result, if something isn't in a FOLLOW set, it certainly isn't in the lookahead set for a LALR(1) parser, though the converse isn't true.